# Return generic Vec

Tags: generics, struct, rust, traits

Say I have a struct like this:

```
struct A {
    field0: u32,
    field1: Vec<B>,
}

struct B {
    field0: f64,
    field1: String,
    field2: Vec<C>,
}

struct C {
    field0: Vec<u8>,
    field1: bool,
}
```

I want to implement a trait for each struct which outputs field with a Vec in it.

```
// snip
trait MyVec<T> {
    fn myvec(&self) -> Vec<T>;
}

impl MyVec<T> for A {
    fn myvec(&self) -> Vec<T> { // return Vec<B>
        &self.field1
    }
}
impl MyVec<T> for B {
    fn myvec(&self) -> Vec<T> { // return Vec<C>
        &self.field2
    }
}
impl MyVec<T> for C {
    fn myvec(&self) -> Vec<T> { // return Vec<u8>
        &self.field0
    }
}
```

But compiler complains `expected type parameter T but found struct B`. How do I do this properly?

Sorry if this is stupid question, I am very new to Rust and don't know first thing about generics or traits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify `T`. i.e.:

```
impl MyVec<B> for A {
    fn myvec(&self) -> Vec<B> {
        &self.field1
    }
}
```

That is, `A` doesn't implement `MyVec<T>` for *any arbitrary* `T` - it only implements it for `B`.

You could also remove the type parameter and use an associated type instead:

```
trait MyVec {
    type Item;
    fn myvec(&self) -> Vec<Self::Item>;
}

impl MyVec for A {
    type Item = B;
    fn myvec(&self) -> Vec<B> {
        &self.field1
    }
}
```